# Jest coverage is not 100% because defaultProp function should be covered with test

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a component and when i'm covering it with tests - coverage is not 100%, because default prop function is not covered

```
Favorites.defaultProps = {
  toggleFavorite: () => {} - is NOT COVERED
};
```

I don't know how can i test default prop function, because i have tests for click events and already calling toggleFavorite() function. See the first test `handles toggle favorite`. So in this test i'm calling that function.

Please advice me what am i doing wrong and why coverage is not 100%.

My component:

```
    export const Favorites = ({ id, metadata, toggleFavorite, isFavorite }) => {
      const [isFavorites, setIsFavorites] = React.useState(isFavorite);

      useEffect(() => {
        setIsFavorites(isFavorite);
      }, [isFavorite]);

      const toggleFavoriteStatus = () => {
        setIsFavorites(!isFavorites);
        const { cmosCatalogId, cmosItem } = metadata;

        toggleFavorite({ id, cmosCatalogId, cmosItem }, isFavorites);
      };

      return (
        <Container>
          <FavButton
            aria-label={isFavorites ? 'Remove from favorites' : 'Add to favorites'}
            onClick={toggleFavoriteStatus}
            data-testid="favorite-button"
          >
            <FavImage
              className="fav-btn-img"
              style={{ opacity: isFavorites ? 1 : 0.3 }}
              src={isFavorites ? selectedFavIcon : favOverIcon}
              alt={favOverIcon}
            />
          </FavButton>
        </Container>
      );
    };

    Favorites.propTypes = {
      id: PropTypes.string,
      metadata: PropTypes.object,
      isFavorite: PropTypes.any,
      toggleFavorite: PropTypes.func,
    };

    Favorites.defaultProps = {
      id: '',
      metadata: {},
      isFavorite: false,
      toggleFavorite: () => {},
    };
```

Tests:

```
describe('Favorites component', () => {
  it('handles toggle favorite', () => {
    const props = getProps();
    const { container } = render(<Favorites {...props} />);

    const { cmosCatalogId, cmosItem } = props.metadata;
    const { id } = props;

    fireEvent.click(queryByTestId(container, 'favorite-button'));
    expect(props.toggleFavorite).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(props.toggleFavorite).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ id, cmosCatalogId, cmosItem }, props.isFavorite);
  });

  it('should have aria-label equals to Add to favorites if isFavorite is false', () => {
    const props = getProps({
      isFavorite: false,
    });

    const { container } = render(<Favorites {...props} />);

    expect(queryByTestId(container, 'favorite-button').getAttribute('aria-label')).toBe('Add to favorites');
  });

  it('should have aria-label equals to Remove from favorites if isFavorite is true', () => {
    const props = getProps({
      isFavorite: true,
    });

    const { container } = render(<Favorites {...props} />);

    expect(queryByTestId(container, 'favorite-button').getAttribute('aria-label')).toBe('Remove from favorites');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a test which renders the component without the `toggleFavorite` prop passed in; that way `Favorites.defaultProps.toggleFavorite` will be called when toggleFavoriteStatus is called

```js
    const { toggleFavourite: _, ...props } = getProps({
      isFavorite: true,
    });

    const { container } = render(<Favorites {...props} />);
```

Comment: Gives an error: Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

Comment: ```
 it('calls default toggle favorite function', () => {
    const { toggleFavourite: _, ...props } = getProps({
      isFavorite: true,
    });

    render(<Favorites {...props} />);

    expect(Favorites.defaultProps.toggleFavorite).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: perhaps set
`Favorites.defaultProps.toggleFavorite = jest.fn()` before `render` in your test

Comment: still an error

expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenCalled()

    Expected number of calls: >= 1
    Received number of calls:    0


It says that received value must be a mock or a spy function

Comment: That's because `jest.fn()` creates a new spy function.
`expect(Favorites.defaultProps.toggleFavorite).toHaveBeenCalled()`

Answer (score 0):

Please try spying on default prop function and then invoke a click. with this approach we can assert the default function called / called with params. I also, do not have luck with the coverage report even after executing below code unfortunately.

```
//setup
jest.spyOn(Favorites.defaultProps,'toggleFavorite');
//trigger
const { container } = render(<Favorites {...props} />);
const { cmosCatalogId, cmosItem } = props.metadata;
const { id } = props;
fireEvent.click(queryByTestId(container, 'favorite-button'));
//assert
expect(Favorites.defaultProps.toggleFavorite).toHaveBeenCalled();
```